# Entity Framework 6 - is it possible to add command interceptor only for specific dbContext

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework-6, interceptor

I need to intercept all queries for specific context but my interceptor catches queries from other contexts, is it possible to register it for specific context only?

I only need to modify queries going to an Oracle database but this solution catches querys from context that is related to mssql database.
Also I register my contexts with Autofac.

Is there any better way to modify EF6 generated query before execution?

```
class OracleDbCommandInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    public void NonQueryExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
    }

    public void NonQueryExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
    }

    public void ReaderExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
    }

    public void ReaderExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
    }

    public void ScalarExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
    }

    public void ScalarExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
    }
}
```

and this is how my context looks like

```
public abstract class OracleDbContext : oracleDb
{
    static OracleDbContext()
    {
        DbInterception.Add(new OracleDbCommandInterceptor());
    }
}
```

and this is generated by edmx

```
public partial class oracleDb: DbContext
{
    public oracleDb()
        : base("name=oracleDb")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Employees> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add command interceptor only for specific dbContext *instance*, you could condition installing the interceptor on a flag passed into the constructor.

```
public abstract class OracleDbContext : oracleDb
{
    OracleDbContext(bool installInterceptor)
    {
        if(installInterceptor)
            DbInterception.Add(new OracleDbCommandInterceptor());
    }
}
```

OracleDbContext instances created like this will install an interceptor.

```
using(OracleDbContext ctx = new OracleDbContext(true)) {
    // Query will be intercepted.
    IEnumerable<Enployee> employees = ctx.Employees.Where(e => ...
}
```

OracleDbContext instances created like this will not install an interceptor.

```
using(OracleDbContext ctx = new OracleDbContext(false)) {
    // Query will not be intercepted.
    IEnumerable<Enployee> employees = ctx.Employees.Where(e => ...
}
```

Comment: Does this separate the interceptor from other DBContexts?

Comment: Only the OracleDbContext instances you create with installInterceptor = True will install an interceptor.

Comment: Surely the OP knows that.  My impression from the question is that it is intercepting calls from all queries, which either means that all DBContexts are aware of the interception, or the DBContext contains references to both Oracle and other databases.

Comment: Yes I need to separate it from other contexts, like context that is connected to mssql databases, this solution still catches all querys, also I am using Autofac where I register contexts